# I can't use variable from @props in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
@props(['active' => false])
@php
    $classes = 'block text-left px-3 text-sm leading-6 hover:bg-blue-500 focus:bg-blue-500` `hover:text-white focus:text-white';
    if ($active) $classes .= ' bg-blue-500 text-white';
@endphp

<a {{ $attributes(['class'=> $classes]) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</a>
```

If statement doesn't access to `$active` variable, how can I fix it

Comment: Do you get "undefined variable $active" ? what do you mean by "If statement doesn't access to $active variable"

Comment: How are you using this component? Where is the error coming from?